# Exclude dependency from project in multi-module SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to exclude some dependencies from submodule in multi module SBT project.

Let's say we have SBT project with modules `a` and `b`. Module `a` has `libraryA` added as its dependency. Module `b` depends on module `a`, but cannot have `libraryA` in its classpath.

SBT build definition:

```
lazy val a: Project = project.
  settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      libraryA
    )
  )
lazy val b: Project = project.dependsOn(a)
```

Is it possible to exclude `libraryA` from module `b` when calling `dependsOn(a)`?

Comment: Surely if project B is dependent on project A, then libraryA becomes a transitive dependency?

Comment: @JonnyCoombes right, but is it possible to exclude it from projectB? I can't find such case in SBT documentation.

Comment: Would you be able to build and then use Project B standalone then though - given that project A depends on the library?